# Draw a Clock using tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am trying to make a clock with the `tkz-euclide` package using a for loop. I have tried to get it to work but it keeps giving me errors. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \radius{5cm}
    \def \n{12}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\radius)
  %  \tkzDefPoint(90-360/12:5){B}
  %  \tkzDefPoint(90-360/12:4){C}
  %  \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
  %  \tkzLabelPoint[below](C){1}
  %  \tkzDrawPoint(B)
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
  {
  \tkzDefPoint(90-1*(360/\n):\radius){t_\i}
  \tkzDrawPoint(t_\i)
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems to be having problems understanding the angle in the `\tkzDefPoint` command. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is `! FP error: Illegal character c found in float number!.`. The `c` in question is that in `5cm`. Looks like you need a unitless number here, so remove `cm` from the definition of `\n`. You need to add it back in `\tkzDrawCircle` though.

And of course you want to multiply by `\i` not `1` in the loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \radius{5}
    \def \n{12}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\radius cm)
  %  \tkzDefPoint(90-360/12:5){B}
  %  \tkzDefPoint(90-360/12:4){C}
  %  \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
  %  \tkzLabelPoint[below](C){1}
  %  \tkzDrawPoint(B)
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
  {
  \tkzDefPoint(90-\i*360/\n:\radius){t_\i}
  \tkzDrawPoint(t_\i)
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if I needed to use parenthesis in expressions for coordinates  what are some tips to avoid the parser from freaking out. I vaguely recall in some cases you use {} to enclose something more complicated.

Comment: @1028 If you need parentheses in the calculation, for example if you have `sin(x)` or `(a+b)/2`, then you need braces as well. The reason is that when reading a coordinate `(x,y)`, the parser typically looks for the closing parenthesis, so a parenthesis in one of the coordinates will mess things up.